# How to perform the pre save hook functionality when updating

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query, hook, mongoose-schema

In my document I have some properties called **height, weight, BMI**. I used the pre save hook to calculate and store the **BMI** on document create or save. But I want to Update the BMI whenever the height or weight is updated.

**//this is the pre save hook that I used**

```
studentSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  this.bmi = calcBMI(this.height, this.weight);
  next();
});
```

**//BMI Calculating Function**

```
exports.calcBMI = (height, weight) => {
  const heightInMeters = height / 100;
  const bmi = (weight / heightInMeters ** 2).toFixed(2);
  return bmi;
};
```

**This function works well when I create a new student.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isModified()` helper function on a document property and check if it's change or not

```js
studentSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  const std = this;
  if(std.isModified("height") || std.isModified("weight")){
   this.bmi = calcBMI(this.height, this.weight)
}
  next();
});
```

Comment: Please can you explain it a little bit more..

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. But still this is not working

Comment: what's the calcBMI implementation

Comment: exports.calcBMI = (height, weight) => {
  const heightInMeters = height / 100;
  const bmi = (weight / heightInMeters ** 2).toFixed(2);
  return bmi;
}; this function works when i create a new student but not working for update

Comment: unfortunately pre save hook does not work properly with `update( )` and `findOneAndUpdate( )` try combination of `findById( )` and `save( )`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use mongoose setters in schema like:

```
const studentSchema = new Schema({
  weight: {
    type: Number,
    set: () => this.bmi = calcBMI(this.height, this.weight);
  },
...same with height
});
```

official mongoose page: [mongoose setters page](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/getters-setters.html)

Comment: Please can you explain it a little bit more... still this is not working :(

Comment: send more code in the answer to help you